# VLC flashing multiple times, cannot resume videos

Tags: 20.04, video, vlc, budgie

On Ubuntu Budgie 20.04.2 (all updates applied, 16GB ram, SSD, desktop, dual display), and VLC 3.0.9.2-1, when I watch a long video and then stop before the end, when I re-open the video VLC flashes several times and there is no "continue" button in the upper right that I am used to.

If I concentrate, in all the flashes, I can see the "continue" button in one of the flashes but it disappears far too quickly for me to click it (maybe it shows for 50ms).

I tried changing the setting for continue as "ask" and "always" but this makes no difference. I have changed single instance mode between checked and not checked but this makes no difference.

This has been going on for more than a month. I was hoping it was just a bug which would be fixed in an update but since it has not changed, I'm coming here for help.

Any ideas?

Comment: If it was me i would be asking on the VLC forum https://www.videolan.org/support/#help fast and good support.

Comment: Thanks @David. After 12 days, not one answer from the VLC forum.